# Craigslist Web Scraper - Clicking "Next Page" Button.. Returning only a blank list [ ]

Tags: python, web-scraping, craigslist

Thanks for coming by... I really appreciate your help. I'm trying to scrape simple craigslist lists, and this code won't work... please help!! Returning empty list [ ] ...
Please help...
The code is followed below..

## importing packages

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
import sys, codecs, locale
import pandas as pd

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True, parser='html.parser')
```

## defining function to scrape data from trips

```
def getTrips(website) :
    browser.open(website)

    trips = browser.find_all(class_='result-info')

    data = []
    for trip in trips: 
        title = get_title(trip)
        url = get_url(trip)
        data.append({
            "title": title,
            "url": url,
            "website": website
        })
    next_page = browser.get_link('next >')
    if next_page:
        getTrips(browser._build_url(next_page.get('href')))
    return data

def get_title(trip):
    if trip.find(class_='result-title hdrlnk'):
        return trip.find(class_='result-title hdrlnk').text
    else:
        return "Title not found"

def get_url(trip):
    if trip.find(class_='result-info'):
        return item.find('a').get('href')
    else:
        return "URL not found"
```

## make aggregated list (*final output = dictionaries with a list called "total")

```
total = []
total.extend(getTrips('https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/bbb?query=photographer&sort=rel'))
```

## print (testing purpose)

```
print(total)
```

## Exporting data into a csv file

```
df = pd.DataFrame(total)
df.to_csv('photographer_data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi! This code won't work... please help!! Returning empty list [ ] ... I have no idea.. please help..

Comment: Please edit the question, add language tag. And remove fluff comment.